# How to condense (or abstract) multiple if and elif statements?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a program for hypothetical venture capitalists in Tkinter to input their last year and second last year revenue amount their businesses earned. The program will sum up the amount, analyse it and assign points (ranging from 0 to 18). 18 is a full score, which means revenue is high. 0 is the lowest score, which means revenue is too low.

To be specific in the program, I set increments of $50,000 (for example, earning any total value between $100,000 and $150,000 in revenue would add 1 point, earning any total value between $150,000 and $200,000 in revenue would add 2 points, etc. all the way to 18).

Because that would occupy many lines of code and would not be efficient, is there a better way to abstract all this? I still want to preserve specificity.

Here is the code:

```
TotalPoints = 0

def SumOfTwoYearRevenue():
    global TotalPoints
    LastYearRevenue = (float(Revenue_LastYear.get()))
    SecondLastYearRevenue = (float(Revenue_SecondLastYear.get()))

    Sum = LastYearRevenue + SecondLastYearRevenue

    if Sum < 100000:
        pass
    elif Sum >= 100000 and Sum < 150000:
        TotalPoints = TotalPoints + 1
    elif Sum >= 150000 and Sum < 200000:
        TotalPoints = TotalPoints + 2
    elif Sum >= 200000 and Sum < 250000:
        TotalPoints = TotalPoints + 3
    elif Sum >= 250000 and Sum < 300000:
        TotalPoints = TotalPoints + 4
    elif Sum >= 300000 and Sum < 350000:
        TotalPoints = TotalPoints + 5
    elif Sum >= 350000 and Sum < 400000:
        TotalPoints = TotalPoints + 6

#etc... all the way until "TotalPoints = TotalPoints + 18"
```

Comment: Something like `while Sum > TotalPoints*50000: TotalPoints += 1`. I can come up with more ways too.

Comment: @Tobias, using a `while` loop won't be efficient.

Comment: @KeyurPotdar I'd argue since the number of comparisions is so low anyhow it doesn't matter

Comment: @Tobias huh, I don't understand the part: while Sum > TotalPoints*50000 . Because won't TotalPoints be 0 at the beginning?

Comment: This is a great candidate for [CodeReview.se] (note that their question format is slightly different, so be sure to read their Tour and How to Ask pages).

Answer (score 1):

At first glance your code would be more nicely represented by a `switch` statement available in languages such as C but not in python.

However, if you look at it more closely, then you will realize that you probably do not need a bunch of conditional statements anyways and would be better suited by using something like the following:

```
if Sum < 100000:
    pass

TotalPoints = TotalPoints + (Sum // 50000) - 1
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes. "//" will divide to the closer integer representation.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should work:

```
TotalPoints += max(0, Sum//50000 - 1)
```